# Python library `arrow` throws AttributeError: unknown attribute: "months"

Tags: python, pip

I'm in process of upgrading an existing project. After upgrading `arrow` to 0.17.0, it starts throwing an exception when on attribute of `months`.

The issue goes away if downgrade `arrow` to 0.13.x; but I hope to upgrade to the latest version and fix the issue in the good way. Any input will be highly appreciated.

```
  ...
  File "/data/app/PROJECT/projectapp/rest/views.py", line 219, in get_precache_redeemable_codes
    create_ts__gte=arrow.now().replace(months=-1).datetime)) \
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arrow/arrow.py", line 807, in replace
    raise AttributeError('unknown attribute: "{}"'.format(key))
AttributeError: unknown attribute: "months"
```

In my application source code, the triggering function call is:

```
create_ts__gte=arrow.now().replace(months=-1).datetime)) \
  .select_related('customer') \
  .prefetch_related('orderitem_set')
```

The full trace of exception:

```
[27/Jan/2021 14:44:32] ERROR [django.request:230] Internal Server Error: /api/redeem/precache/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/app/PROJECT/projectapp/rest/views.py", line 219, in get_precache_redeemable_codes
    create_ts__gte=arrow.now().replace(months=-1).datetime)) \
  File "/data/app/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arrow/arrow.py", line 807, in replace
    raise AttributeError('unknown attribute: "{}"'.format(key))
AttributeError: unknown attribute: "months"
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `months` with `month`?

Comment: But you are using wrong method. `replace` as name suggest replaces and got only kwarg `month` for replacing month and this must be integer in range `1..12`. What you want to do is `shift`, `shift` can take kwarg `months=-1`

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Take_Care_. Yes, you provided the correct answer. I changed it to `arrow.now().shift(months=-1)...` and it works for me now.